# Where should I store (place) my own exceptions in C++?

Tags: c++, exception

Suppose I need to create many of *my own* exceptions which I will use in my `C++` application. The question is *Where should I place those exceptions?* I mean I could place them in some header file:

```
#ifndef MYEXCEPTIONS_H
#define MYEXCEPTIONS_H

#include <exception>

class exc1 : public std::exception
{
  virtual const char* what() const throw() {
    return "exc1 was caught!";
  }
};
/*other similar exceptions*/
#endif
```

And then just include this file where I want to catch my exceptions. Or I could create namespace and place them there.

Is there some suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Exception objects are like any other object. The declarations should go in a header file (potentially with inline implementations for simple methods), and should be declared in a namespace with semantic meaning to your application and/or library.

Comment: Do you really need custom exceptions?  You could just use [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) and you can pass it a string that will be used if the caller calls `what()`.

Comment: @NathanOliver it is useful at times to define custom exceptions, especially when you need to catch and differentiate between different exception types. Even the STL defines multiple exception types for this purpose. A `try` can have multiple `catch` to do different things for different errors, or to catch only specific errors while letting others continue up the call chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And then just include this file where I want to catch my exceptions.

Yes. You will need to include the file where you throw that exception too.

> Or I could create namespace and place them there.

There is no need for an **Or** here. It's more like:

**And** you could create a namespace that is specific to your app and put the exception class in the namespace.